# How to perform BFS from the bottom to up of tree for MINMAX algorithm?

Tags: java, recursion, tree, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Every node has an `ArrayList<Node>` of children.

Leafes are already evaluated. I want to set value for all nodes above leafs level by level, so I must set value for all nodes on certain level to go to their parrents and set value for them.

**In another words**: `1` suppose to be set for nodes on level `X` before it will be set for nodes on level `X-1`

**In another words2**: I need to set node.evaluation = 1, for all leaves on level X before I go closer to root.

How to do so? I tried that below but it seems to be wrong. I attempt it for a week now.

```
evaluateTree2(root);
    ....
public void evaluateTree2(Node node){
        for(Node descendant  : node.children) {
            evaluateTree2(descendant);  
            node.evaluation = 1;
            }       
}
```

Comment: the bottom of the tree is normally the leaves

Comment: @martijnn2008 Yes, and I want to start from leaves and to back to root level by level, I need to set node.evaluation = 1, for all leaves on level X before I go closer to root.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a stack and a queue. Pseudocode for printing the nodes level by level from bottom to top: (Note that the order of putting children in my_queue migth matter to your application).

Time complexity is O(n). insert and pop in both stack and queue is O(1), given n elements and n pop and insert in each, the total order is linear, i.e. O(n).

```
Stack my_stask
Queue my_queue

insert tree.root into my_queue

while my_queue != empty
  pop Node node from my_queue
  push node.children into my_queue
  push node into my_stask

while my_stask != empty
  pop Node node from my_stask
  print node
```

Comment: Could you please attach any code I don't get it and I do not see recursion in it.

Comment: Do you need it to be recursive?

Comment: No, it hasn't but I don't undrestand what have you have written. "Put a node in queue, pop it" so why put if you pop it in next line? Also how to traverse a tree without recursion.

Comment: Finally I used `TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Node>>`. Queue in java has linear time complexity when adding elements.

Comment: As far as I know time complexity for push and pop in queue in most standard libraries is O(1). Even if there is nothing in Java, you can always implement one with a linked list. If you have found another solution, would you please provide the code?

Comment: Thanks Mahshid -- this really helped me elegantly solve my problem. I needed to find the order of execution of a collection of multiply-interconnected blocks.

Comment: Just in case any future readers are confused like Yoda was - a "queue" pops from the START of the list (the head), so it's not "put a node in queue, pop it", it's "put a node on the end of the queue, pop a node from the head of the queue"